# How to login again after logout ubuntu in Trying ubuntu live CD

Tags: login, live-environment

I try Ubuntu 14.04 by using live CD and I logout that and now I can't login again because it asks me input username and password. I don't know what I should enter the usename and password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The username should be ubuntu, and the password is blank

Comment: that didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.